# Can Chef modify UAC to allow silent installs?

Tags: windows, chef-infra, uac, chef-recipe

I am able to silently install numerous programs. However I hit a problem with certain ones which prompt the UAC to appear, this throws off the silent install and does not run.

If I manually turn the UAC off, the program installs silently. 
However, this requires user interaction and I am currently building a project which is meant to limit user interaction.

Is Chef able to modify the UAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef, by default, runs as the Local System god account. This gives it greater-than admin privileges. You can make use of powershell with those privileges to do just about anything on a windows server. For example, to disable UAC add this one line of code to your recipe

`powershell_out('New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force')`

The question really isn't 'Can Chef do it?', it is 'Can powershell do it?' and the answer almost always is yes.

Comment: This seems to have done it. I am assuming it can be reversed just as easily.

Comment: I haven't tried it but this is a simple registry edit so the reverse should be just as easy.

Comment: It appears that using your answer in the Recipe is temporary, so once it has ran the UAC will reset to default. This means I do not have to reverse the code. Thank you for your help